# How to locate In-wall speaker cables (behind dry wall)

Tags: electrical, drywall, speakers, locating

I moved into my new house about a year ago and discovered a wall plate that has 4 pairs of speaker wires stuffed in there. According to the labels on the ends of the wires, there are speakers for our patio, family room, living room, and kitchen. The patio speakers are actually connected and work just fine. But the others must be just hanging behind the walls in the various rooms (The previous owner chose not to install speakers).

So does anyone know how to trace or locate these cables without opening up the walls? Is there some kind of signal or ping that I can send down the cables and then have a way to locate them through the dry wall?

Any help would be hugely appreciated!

Comment: I've used the [Gardner Bender Multi-Purpose Wire Tracer](http://m.homedepot.com/p/Gardner-Bender-Multi-Purpose-Wire-Tracer-1-Clam-5Clams-Master-GET-4220K/100192834), and it was able to pick up wires within the wall.

Comment: "Fox and Hound" is another product name to look for.

Comment: Have you ruled out, the possibility, of the wires not being in a wall cavity at all, but laying in the attic above, or floor space below, the rooms in question?

Comment: Hey guys...many thanks for the replies!!! Yes I actually have the wire tracer, but so far no pings! And since all of the speaker wires are ear-marked for locations on the first floor, I have no attic space to crawl into. But a good thought about looking under the floor. There is a crawl space that I can take a look at (it's tight). I will try that tomorrow morning. Thanks again!